# What to do aftert STARTTLS in raw socket connection to SMTP server in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, starttls

I try to connect to SMTP server by using System.Net.Sockets.Socket. I can send e-mails without problems if there is no STRARTTLS command and I just connect to port 25, send HELO, MAIL FROM, RCTP TO, MAIL etc and my e-mail is send.
Now I need to connect to another server and use STARTTLS before I can send any e-mail and I do not know what to do after I send STARTTLS and get successful response from SMTP server. If I send any command after I receive STARTTLS response, server does not return any response and I cannot send next commands.

I found something like this but I have no idea what "starts TLS negotiation" means and how I can do it in C#/.NET to be able to send next commands.

> S: <waits for connection on TCP port 25>    C: 
> S: 220 mail.imc.org SMTP service ready    C: EHLO mail.example.com
> S: 250-mail.imc.org offers a warm hug of welcome    S: 250-8BITMIME
> S: 250-STARTTLS    S: 250 DSN    C: STARTTLS    S: 220 Go ahead    C: starts TLS negotiation C & S: negotiate a TLS session  C & S:
> check result of negotiation    C: EHLO mail.example.com    S:
> 250-mail.imc.org touches your hand gently for a moment    S:
> 250-8BITMIME    S: 250 DSN

source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207#section-5

Comment: You do as it says, no? Start negotiating a secure channel..

Comment: *I do not know what to do after I send STARTTLS* - are you actually writing your own SMTP client? Or are you just using e.g. MimeKit/MailKit to send an email?

Comment: It is my own SMTP client. I do not how I can "Start negotiating a secure channel" in C#. That is the main problem.

Comment: Just curious a) why you're bothering and b) why not just look at what e.g. MailKit does